# How to create batch file that delete files by words at the end of file name (using a list of words)?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch

I have a directory with thousands of `html` files scattered across several subdirectories. I need to delete all files matching any one of many criteria. All criteria are similar by kind. The file names are like:

```
MM-DD_hh-mm-ss__www.host.com.html
```

So, all files that are ending in certain hostnames must be deleted. There are about 20 hostnames for now. (But that number will increase to about 100.) I store a list in `txt` file and prefer to do so.

```
__first.site.com.html
__www.secondsite.com_.html
__site.com_numberthree.html
```

The thing is, some "good" files contain "bad" hostnames but not at end of file name.

```
__www.onesite.com_.html (bad)
__www.onesite.com_prices.html (good)
```

Can I create a bach file to safely scan all subdirectories and remove unnecessary files using the list? OS is Windows 7. I want to set up Task Scheduler to run such butch each night. But I'm not familiar with commands. Please help.

P.S. In fact, some "bad" files have linked folders `_files`. I expect they will be deleted automatically like it happens when I manually delete main `html` file.

Comment: We are not here to do your work for you. Try so solve it yourself and when you get stuck on a **specific** problem, ask about that. I can however say that batch isn't the correct tool for the job. There are several better scripting languages for windows you can use. For example powershell, perl, python or even javascript.

Comment: @Nifle I apologize for disappearing. "Try so solve it yourself and when you get stuck on a specific problem, ask about that." Yes, I got it. I will try PowerShell. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quickie to get you started:

```
@echo off

for /F %%p in (list.txt) do (
    echo Current pattern: %%p
    for /R "C:\" %%f in (*%%p*) do (
        echo File: %%f
    )
)

exit /B 0
```

Comment: This dosn't work for good files with bad host names.

Comment: @Endoro: why not?

Comment: this will "delete" `__www.onesite.com_prices.html`

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the "bad" and "good" (poor) explanation in the question.

Comment: @Vlastimil, thank you for your time. I'm sorry for poor explanation.

Comment: @MirosavKostyakov, no problem. This answer just won't be the solution.